# pro*c: junk printed while trying to print spanish characters from a specific program

Tags: c, linux

Before I begin, I would like to say that this is not an issue with pro*c. I have tested this tiny program below and it works.

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char string[100];
        char str1[100];
        sprintf(string, "á, é, í, ó, ú");
        strcpy(str1, "Código_de_la_unidad");
        printf("[%s]\n", string);
        printf("[%s]\n", str1);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1604_MX/src/batch/cycle> ./test
[á, é, í, ó, ú]
[Código_de_la_unidad]
```

Now my issue is here.
When I use the same chunk of codes in another program kc760.pc (which is a very large program and I cannot paste all of it here), it prints junk in the place of special characters.

kc760.pc's source (only the useful part):

```
     char out_record[100];
     char tips_out_record[121];
     int  debug = 0;

char *countryLoc;

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
/*==================================================================
//      Local Variables Defined
==================================================================*/
        char string[100];
        char str1[100];

        sprintf(string, "á, é, í, ó, ú");
        strcpy(str1, "Código_de_la_unidad");
        printf("[%s]\n", string);
        printf("[%s]\n", str1);

        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        FILE *sam = fopen("/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1604_MX/src/batch/cycle/sample", "r");
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, sam)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

        exit(0);

    int report_seq_counter;
    int header_switch;
    int rc;

    countryLoc = getenv("LOCATION");

    if(countryLoc == NULL){
        printf("The env variable LOCATION is not set. Exiting !!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

kc760's output:

[image]

Please focus on the first two lines in the output. They are printed due to strcpy/ sprintf operation. **it prints junk**. Now, please focus on the last four lines of the output and you will find that the special spanish characters are getting printed just fine (which is achieved by reading them from a file).

Please see the content of the file also which is read by this program:

```
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1604_MX/src/batch/cycle> cat sample
[á, é, í, ó, ú]
[Código_de_la_unidad]
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1604_MX/src/batch/cycle>
```

Can you please help me to understand what possibly is causing this issue.
Please note that this program has been in use for almost 2 decades and this is the first time I observed this issue while implementing spanish characters.

Please let me know if I can help with more information.

Comment: The fact that the correct line has length 21 indicates that your sample file and terminal uses UTF-8. The likely reason why it fails with your literals is that your source file is saved in a pre-UTF-8 encoding. If you want to do it right, you need to be aware of what encoding each input file, output file, terminal, data structure and string literal contains or expects, and convert accordingly. If you don't care and just want it to appear to work right now on your terminal, use hex escapes.

Comment: have you tried `wcscpy`?

Comment: Perhaps a source file encoding issue?

Comment: @Dinesh: `wcscpy` fails during compilation for special spanish character. The error is `kc760.c:1354:17: error: converting to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`

Comment: @thatotherguy : You hit the right spot. I converted the source into UTF-8 but lost all special characters which had tick on the top of it. I had to insert those chars again. After build it worked. You might want to post your comment in the answer section. But I still don't understand why a character which is correctly visible in the non-UTF-8 encoding is turned into junk when compiled and run. Do you have any idea?